# How to call the office-365 version of Excel from ASP.NET in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, office365, office-interop

Currently we have Word & Excel-2003 installed on our server.  And ASP.NET can produce Excel forms.
But when I tried to import a newer style .xlsx, and read it in, of course it was not going to work.

So I installed O-365 with an Office-365-license, including Excel.  Then I was receiving errors for all calls to Excel & Word.  I was able to revert and uninstall and get the old way to work again.

But how do I get the newer version to function?  I have googled this a couple of times and couldn't find definitive answers.  Some-say.. well you need to 'impersonate'.  Well that could be... because my O-365 is licensed under a certain user.  Others say its something with app-pool settings.  But I believe that is some-sorta rabbit hole for this problem.  Because it was working before I installed O-365, and is now working again.

If it is to be that I need to impersonate in the web-config.. And add a user to the machine.  I can see some potential problems with that.  I feel it would be better if I could just make use a user, when in the time to call to Excel: in the **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** calls?  Or do I need to impersonate in web.config for the global application?  Or is there an entirely different solution.

Edit: Sorry, I didn't post the error. After I installed O-365.  And tried to run the site with simple Excel calls.  It would report:
Event code: 4011
Event message: An unhandled access exception has occurred.

Interestingly... Most of the time these 'WEB-STOPPING' errors show up as 'yellow-triangle' warnings.  But this just comes up as 'information'.

Answer (score 1):

Office interop, for both 2003 and 365, relies on certain libraries referenced in the application. When moving from 2003 to 365 you must also update the app to reference the newer version of the interop libraries.

Also be aware that licensing for 365 is different: by default the license is checked per user on the system. While you may have setup 365 to have a valid license with your user account, it's doubtful this license was activated properly for whatever user account is running the web application. Make this work correctly takes some extra steps.

However, interop is far from the best option for generating Excel files from a web server.

Comment: But I didn't uninstall the 2003..Excel.  It was still installed.  The newer office was blocking its function?
Actually, now I think about it.  In order to restore its function I had to edit the registry and delete an empty key that contained 1.9 and I assume the key for the 2003 was one of the earlier ones.

Comment: The newer version of Excel would have been the default application for opening Excel files.

Comment: So its a two-fold procedure.  I need to install-O-365.  And update my code to have these newer Interop libraries.  makes sense... d'oh, not dollars.

Comment: Yep... this is why you need a test environment. You want a separate server with the old Excel installed, where you can validate the process of installing new Excel, pushing updating code with references to the new libraries, and then verify it works after both are done -- without impacting production.

Comment: Heres the odd part... The test server environment has both O-365 and older ones installed...hmm  But there are some differences.

Comment: Thank-fully... only our administrative-staff actually uses 'Excel' forms.  not customers.

Comment: I bet the test server will still open Excel files by default in the old Excel... at least for the user account running the web site.